# Getting Permission Denied error while accessing a file in Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, testing, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy a model on AWS Sagemaker and using the following docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
 wget \
 python3.5-dev \
 gcc \
 nginx \
 ca-certificates \
 libgcc-5-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Here we get all python packages.
# There's substantial overlap between scipy and numpy that we eliminate by
# linking them together. Likewise, pip leaves the install caches populated which uses
# a significant amount of space. These optimizations save a fair amount of space in the
# image, which reduces start up time.
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.3/get-pip.py && python3.5 get-pip.py && \
    pip3 install numpy==1.14.3 scipy lightfm scikit-optimize pandas==0.22.0 flask gevent gunicorn && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache

# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

# Set up the program in the image
COPY lightfm /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

The docker container is built successfully, but when I write the following command:

```
docker run XYZ train
```

on my local or even on Sagemaker, I am getting the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "permission denied"
```

In the docker file I am copying a folder called Lightfm and there is a file called "train" in it.

Can anyone help?

***OUTPUT OF MY DOCKER BUILD:***

```
$ docker build -t lightfm .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  41.47kB
Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 5e13f8dd4c1a
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  wget  python3.5-dev  gcc  nginx  ca-certificates  libgcc-5-dev  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14ae3a1eb780
Step 3/9 : RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.3/get-pip.py && python3.5 get-pip.py &&     pip3 install numpy==1.14.3 scipy lightfm scikit-optimize pandas==0.22.0 flask gevent gunicorn &&     rm -rf /root/.cache
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5a2727e27385
Step 4/9 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 43bf8c5e8414
Step 5/9 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d2c45d61cec
Step 6/9 : ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3cc6313c0d9
Step 7/9 : COPY lightfm /opt/program
 ---> ad929ba84692
Step 8/9 : WORKDIR /opt/program
 ---> Running in a040dd0bab03
Removing intermediate container a040dd0bab03
 ---> 8f53c5a3ba63
Step 9/9 : RUN chmod 755 serve
 ---> Running in 5666abb27cd0
Removing intermediate container 5666abb27cd0
 ---> e80aca934840
Successfully built e80aca934840
Successfully tagged lightfm:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Comment: did the container get built successfully? if not, which line in the Dockerfile failed?

Comment: Yes it got build successfully. I have a folder called lightfm in which there is a file called "train". When I write a command docker run XYZ train, I encounter this issue.

Comment: Edited my question, sorry for missing that out @teng

Comment: I read this the last time of your `error` `SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.` Maybe you need to fix the permissions of the `files/directories`?

Comment: How do I do that ? Can you please suggest?

Comment: The container did get built successfully. I believe the `SECURITY WARNING` is a standard warning when building Linux-based containers in Windows OS.

Comment: My guess is that this error some likely due to docker... see this issue: https://github.com/docker/labs/issues/215 ...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `train` is the executable you want to run, give it exec permission. After `COPY lightfm /opt/program` line, add `RUN chmod +x /opt/program/train`.